# create an object based on the type of another object in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

how to create an object based on the type of another object in TypeScript

`obj1 = new Object();`

`obj2 = new "obj1.constructor.name"`

I have to do like that because `Object 1` can have different class .

Comment: `new obj1.constructor()` should work. BTW this has nothing to do with TypeScript.

Comment: when I use obj1.constructor i ahve this error   
""Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature.""

Comment: Could you please add more information? It is not clear what you really want. Do you want to inherit/extend from another class?

Answer (score 2):

The typescript compiler will complain if you try to do:

```
new obj1.constructor()
```

But you can tell it that it's ok like this:

```
class A {}

class B extends A {}

type AConstructor = {
    new(): A;
}

type BConstructor = {
    new(): B;
}

let a1 = new A();
let a2 = new (a1.constructor as AConstructor)();

let b1 = new B();
let b2 = new (b1.constructor as BConstructor)();
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20A%20%7B%7D%0A%0Aclass%20B%20extends%20A%20%7B%7D%0A%0Atype%20AConstructor%20%3D%20%7B%0A%09new()%3A%20A%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Atype%20BConstructor%20%3D%20%7B%0A%09new()%3A%20B%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Alet%20a1%20%3D%20new%20A()%3B%0Alet%20a2%20%3D%20new%20(a1.constructor%20as%20AConstructor)()%3B%0A%0Alet%20b1%20%3D%20new%20B()%3B%0Alet%20b2%20%3D%20new%20(b1.constructor%20as%20BConstructor)()%3B))